# Can I wrap an if statement around window.location.hostname.includes('ca.') to run a script on Shopify checkout.liquid file?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, shopify, liquid, checkout

I am trying to run a script but only on certain subdomains of a Shopify store. I am wrapping the domain name of the window in an if statement. So the script should only trigger if it's Canada or  Australia subdomain.

```
if (window.location.hostname.includes('ca.') || window.location.hostname.includes('au.') ) {
        //run script
}
```

This seems to work on all pages except checkout.liquid file for Shopify. Any ideas if Shopify liquid files recognizes window.location.hostname?

If I remove the if statement, the code runs on all subdomains. If I add the if statement, the script doesn't work on any domains.

So I know the script works but just need it to only fire on certain subdomains.

Comment: Could you show us the example of the liquid file? By the way, with liquid you can put a **server side** if on the domain https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/request?shpxid=2349105e-2FA9-4B30-5164-7FDFB5F9B0C0#request-host for example `{ % if request.host contains 'ca.' % }`

Comment: Have you logged out for yourself the value of window.location.hostname? Obviously when serving up everything but checkout, the domain name is whatever decoration alias the shop has adopted for DNS. In checkout however, things get transferred to Shopify and perhaps that is where your technique fails? What are the results of that?